# accessing dictionary data from Parse and displaying on Tableview Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, parse-platform

I have an object with dictionary properties I'm trying to access and display on a tableview cell. I haven't dealt with dictionary type data before, so displaying it has kind of confused me..

this is the object. Its from the class PoolAccount and the data i want to access is in the column "serviceHistory"

```
var poolHistory:PFObject = PFObject(className: "PoolAccount")
 Print(poolHistory.valueForKey("serviceHistory")!.count!)
 //returns this data
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
  //How do i cast this data so i can use it in a tableview cell?
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


  cell.textLabel?.text = ??
```

Comment: can you post a picture of the class you have in parse

Comment: i updated it with a couple pictures @Lamar, its an array of dictionary values.

Comment: you have to use the query those objects from the background using **findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock** save it into a dictionary then you could populate it into a cell

Comment: anyway to take the current object not my tableview and cast it into a dictionary?

Comment: i don't really understand what you just said.?

Comment: hahah, sorry, Can i take the current object thats already in the view controller and cast it to a dictionary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87199/discussion-between-lamar-and-steve-derienzo).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change "serviceHistory" column type to Object.
You can use NSDictionary

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

var data = poolHistory["serviceHistory"] as! NSArray

var element = data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
var phValue = element["PH"] as! Int

cell.textLabel?.text = "\(phValue)"

}
```

Comment: I need to save multiple objects to this column, does this column as an object only hold one object or can it consist of an array of objects?

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand your case. i edited code probably this should work. 
in your case you use an array ob objects.

Comment: unfortunately i can only add one object to the column and not multiple objects unless the column is of type array...having a column of object doesn't allow that..